# My website stops until whole content loads?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have made ajax request using the following script...

```
 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'load.php',
 data: 'page='+url,
 dataType: "html",
 beforeSend:function(){

 $('.left').html('<div class="ajax-load"><center><img    src="http://www.cadysalley.com/img/loader.gif" style="margin-top: 33px;" alt="Loading..." /></center></div>');
$('#ajax-load').show();
 },

 success:function(msg){
$('.left').empty();
// successful request; do something with the data
if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
        {

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
            $('.left').html(msg);
            $('#ajax-load').hide();
        }
  },
  error:function(){  

 $('.left').empty();
 $('#ajax-load').hide();
 }
});
```

My problem is that , whenever i click the link, the spinner starts and after that alert pop up,, after alert pop up,, the whole websites pause for some seconds unless the new page is loaded,,,... I want my website not to pause and continue the spinner load untill whole website loads perfectly with the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the new content in the div where you placed the ajax-load div.

```
$('.left').html('<div class="ajax-load"><center><img    src="http://www.cadysalley.com/img/loader.gif" style="margin-top: 33px;" alt="Loading..." /></center></div>');

 $('.left').html(msg);
 $('#ajax-load').hide();
```

You need to place the ajax-loader out side the $('.left') container.

edited

```
ok do this. 
setTimeout(function() {
   $('.left').empty();
// successful request; do something with the data
if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
    {

        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
        $('.left').html(msg);
        $('#ajax-load').hide();
    }
}, 100);
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: I did that also, i placed the loader image outside also,, bt also same problem, the loading images pause and the whole page stops for few seconds and then only loads

Comment: Did you get it working? Put my edited code in the success function. this will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this.. To load your website perfectly..Add one more div before your ('.left') div..Hide the ('.left') till data gets loaded..till then show your ajax loader..when complete data is done through ajax you hide your ajax and show your ('.left')..

Like this..Add a css class

```
.hideIT{
visibility:hidden;      
}

beforeSend:function(){

 $('#newDiv').html('<div class="ajax-load"><center><img    src="http://www.cadysalley.com/img/loader.gif" style="margin-top: 33px;" alt="Loading..." /></center></div>');
$('.left').addClass('hideIT');
$('#ajax-load').show();
 },

 success:function(msg){
$('.left').empty();
// successful request; do something with the data
if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
        {

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
            $('.left').html(msg);
            $('#ajax-load').hide();
            $('.left').removeClass('hideIT');

        }
  },
```

Comment: The problem is not abt hiding and showing,, whenever I click the menu link,  the loader image shows, after that loader image stops and the whole website pause, nothing is clickable, all likks are paused,, whole website pauses or stops for few seconds till the content page loads in the .left